# "Oops, an error occurred" instagram login error

Tags: php, authentication, instagram

For the last five months, my Instagram account won't open. My other accounts have been working fine. Whenever I try to refresh my Instagram account, it just doesn't refresh. When I try to login on a browser, it takes me to a blank page and says **"Oops an error occurred"**.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's an authentication problem, account need to validate but you can't give verification code in SMS or email,
request verification code in SMS or email

```
<?php
set_time_limit(0);
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');

require __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';

use InstagramAPI\Exception\ChallengeRequiredException;
use InstagramAPI\Instagram;
use InstagramAPI\Response\LoginResponse;

//Enter these options
$username            = 'username'; // your username
$password            = 'password'; //your password
$verification_method = 1; //0 = SMS, 1 = Email

//Leave these
$user_id      = '';
$challenge_id = '';

class ExtendedInstagram extends Instagram {
    public function changeUser( $username, $password ) {
        $this->_setUser( $username, $password );
    }
}

$instagram = new ExtendedInstagram();

    $loginResponse = $instagram->login( $username, $password );
    $user_id       = $instagram->account_id;

    if ( $loginResponse !== null && $loginResponse->isTwoFactorRequired() ) {
        echo '2FA not supported in this example';
        exit;
    }

    if ( $loginResponse instanceof LoginResponse || $loginResponse === null ) {
        echo "Not a challenge required exception...\n";
    }

    echo 'Logged in!';
?>
```

[Instagram's private API Library](https://github.com/mgp25/Instagram-API)

Comment: It's account problem, It's not about your PHP code. Open the Instagram Login page, then try to use "Forgot Password".

Answer (score 0):

**[SOLVED]**
i was facing the same problem as " oops a error occurred" when i logged in to my Instagram account i tried resting the password, uninstalling and reinstalling the app but i faced the same problem i was searching to have a contact with the support team , i emailed to "Hi,
*Thanks for contacting us. Before we can help, we need you to confirm that you own this account.*
*Please reply to this email and attach a photo of yourself holding a hand-written copy of the code below.*
*(secret code)*
*Please make sure that the photo you send:*
*- Includes the above code hand-written on a clean sheet of paper, followed by your full name and username*
*- Includes both your hand that's holding the sheet of paper and your entire face*
*- Is well-lit, and is not too small, dark or blurry*
*- Is attached to your reply as a JPEG file*
*Keep in mind that even if this account doesn't include any pictures of you or is used to represent someone or something else, we won't be able to help until we receive a photo that meets these requirements.*
*Thanks,*
*The Instagram Team*

**I sent them the required information and it resolved my problem within 8-12 hours.. i got y account back yupieee :D**